# MySQL count dates from 2 tables but not duplicate dates

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have 2 table in mysql 
1 table  with public holidays in:

```
id   empid      date
1      10     2015-10-17
2      10     2015-12-24
3      10     2016-01-01
4      11     2015-10-17
5      11     2015-12-24
6      11     2016-01-01
```

I have a second table with holidays in

```
id    employeeid           date
1      10               2015-10-15
2      10               2015-10-16
3      10               2015-10-17
4      10               2015-10-18
5      11               2015-11-11
```

The question is how do I join both tables together and do a count with out  counting any  duplicate dates (dates that are in both tables) the count should be  6 days holiday because the 2015-10-17 is in both tables for employee id 10. I have multiple employee id and dates in the table .

```
employee 10 count 6
employee 11 count 4
```

I have tried inner join but can not work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(t.u_date) as employee_count, t.employee_id
from (
    select date as u_date, employee_id
    from table

    union

    select date as u_date, employee_id
    from table
) as t
group by t.employee_id
```

[FIDDLE_EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3689c/4)

EDIT:

for your updated query you can just do this

```
SELECT 
    ...
FROM employees AS e
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT empid, date, hours
    FROM holidays_taken
    UNION
    SELECT empid, date, hours
    FROM public_holidays
) AS h ON e.id = h.empid
WHERE e.id = 1
GROUP BY Year
```

Comment: Either use `UNION` or `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, but not both.

Comment: @John Ruddell So union is the way forward what i am tring to do is integrate the public holiday table into mysql [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/371a7/15) how would I integrate the union into this thanks

Comment: @jonathanyoung what? i can't understand what you said

Comment: @John Ruddell  sorry keypad problem. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/371a7/15) How would I add  your query to the demo I have put up on SQLFIDDLE In my query i am just query the holiday table but I also need to query a second table (public holiday). Thanks

Comment: @jonathanyoung so what is the holidays column in the employee table? and you are already using the holidays_taken table.. I didn't see another one? do you have a public_holidays_taken table?

Comment: The holiday column in the employee table is the amount of days holiday each employee is allowed in 12 months from there start date. I have total days and total hours.  I have added the public holiday table to the new demo. Not sure how to query both the table  [NEW DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c754cd/1)

Comment: @jonathanyoung does the public holiday table not have an hours column? and do you need that?

Comment: @jonathanyoung ok gotcha. you can put the union part in the left join. i'll edit my answer with an example

Comment: [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/289f44/1) I have added the union but it is not adding the day or hour  count from the public holiday table to the result   problem line  ` CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365), COUNT(h.date) AS Holidays_Taken,  SUM(h.hours) AS Hours` Any ideas!

Comment: @jonathanyoung I think the reason why thats not happening is because the empid is 10 and 11 in the public holiday table... and you are filtering out all except for id 1

Comment: LOL Sorry getting late just notice that thanks works great :)